# Setup a TestProject with XCTest with two test targets for iOS and OSX and shared Unit Tests

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode5, xctest

I would like to have a single project for Unit testing a library which executes the unit tests on Mac OS X and iOS, in two separate test targets within one Xcode project. The Unit Test files shall be shared.

It seems this is impossible, or is not intended to work, or otherwise, reveals a bug:

While it's possible to run the complete Unit Test for each iOS and Mac OS X (via command Product -> Test), it's not possible to run *individual* test methods by clicking on the *diamond* in the gutter:

[image]

When doing this, Xcode opens an error sheet, telling:

> **The run destination My Mac 64–bit is not valid for tests you have chosen to perform.**
>
> Please select a run destination which supports the tests that you wish to perform.

[image]

I figured, the problem seems to be that in one project with two targets the shared Unit Test files have to be associated to iOS *and* Mac OS X test targets. That is, the "Target Membership" for a particular Unit Test file is set for the iOS and the MacOSX target.

Starting individual tests from the diamond in the gutter seems to work only, when associating shared Unit Test files to only *one* target.

Has anybody managed to get this working? What would be an alternate solution?

Comment: I have same problem so I just run test from test navigator (CMD+5)

Comment: @xlc Thanks for that info! :) This actually runs individual tests. Yet after a test did run, the corresponding "Diamonds" in the gutter won't get updated to reflect the status of this test (this is a minor problem, but still worth a report)

Comment: Same problem here. It is driving me crazy as well, because that button in the gutter would be soooo nice to use. The bug is reported here as well: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/09/radar-xcode-5-unable-to-configure-inline-unit-tests-for-ios-and-mac-in-parallel/ rdar://15085316

Comment: Doesn't seem to be fixed in Xcode6 Beta5 either. Bummer.

Comment: Still broken in Xcode7 Beta5

Comment: Still broken in 7.2.1.

Comment: Seems to be fixed in 7.3 beta2 and beta3

Answer (score 0):

This will go away if you remove all custom entries for the Architectures (ARCHS) build setting in your main target and test target for each platform.
Relying just on the OSX/IOS Default build setting will then work.

Please note that when you switch between your OSX and IOS schemes you first have to wait until the indexer is trough and you may first need to run all tests for the platform.
After that you can at least start the single test from the Tests Navigator. 
Looks like Xcode sometimes still has issues to display the source code inline test button. Though the possibility to run a single test is there.